# How to compare viewbag value with model another value in mvc 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, razor

I am trying to send viewbag from action method to view. When first page loads viewbag value will be null. when I call CheckPermissions action method viewbag gets some value and it will return the same view that time viewbag contains some value and now I want to compare viewbag value with another value. I tried but following error appearing. Cannot perform runtime binding on a null reference.
This is my Index view code.

```
@model c3card.Models.GroupPermissionVM
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
  @Html.LabelFor(m=>m.GroupID)
  @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.GroupID, Model.GroupList, "Please select", new { id = "ddlgrp" })
    foreach(var permission in Model.Permissions)
    {
        if (ViewBag.marlid.equals(permission))
        {
        <label>
            @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.perm_id, permission.perm_id, new {@checked="true"})
            <span>@permission.perm_levelname</span>
        </label>
        }
        else
        {
            <label>
            @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.perm_id, permission.perm_id)
            <span>@permission.perm_levelname</span>
        </label>

        }
    }
```

This is my action method

```
public ActionResult CheckPermissions(int id)
        {
            var groups = db.tm_grp_group.Where(a => a.grp_isactive == true);
            var permissions = db.tm_perm_level;
            GroupPermissionVM model = new GroupPermissionVM
            {
               marlid=db.ts_grp_perm_mapping.Select(p=>p.grp_id==id).Count(),
                GroupList = new SelectList(groups, "grp_id", "grp_name"),
                Permissions = permissions.Select(p => new PermissionVM
                {
                    perm_id = p.perm_id,
                    perm_levelname = p.perm_levelname

                })
            };
          ViewBag.marlid = db.ts_grp_perm_mapping.Select(p => p.grp_id == id).Count();

            return View("Index",model);
        }
```

Any suggestion why I am not able to compare values inside if condition? Thanks in advance. This line causing me error  if (ViewBag.marlid.equals(permission))
I edited as follows

```
foreach(var permission in Model.Permissions)
    {
       if(Model.marlid==permission.perm_id)
       {
          <label>
            @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.perm_id, permission.perm_id,new { @checked = true } )@Model.marlid.ToString()
            <span>@permission.perm_levelname</span>
        </label>

       }
```

Comment: `if (ViewBag.marlid != null && ViewBag.marlid.equals(permission))`

Comment: You are comparing objects of different type - `ViewBag.marlid` is of type `int`, and `permission` is `PermissionVM`

Comment: I edited now it says 'int' does not contain a definition for 'equals'

Comment: But seriously, why on earth would you do that. If the value of `perm_id` is equal to the value of `permission.perm_id` then it will be selected - there is no need for this code at all (and it screws up model binding). Just set the value of property `perm_id` in the controller before you pass the model to the view

Comment: I want to make selection so whatever comes inside if should be checked. Otherwise unchecked

Comment: Exactly, so set the value of `perm_id` and remove the `if` block and just use `@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.perm_id, permission.perm_id)`

Comment: I am getting value through Model.marlid and it workd as expected when the value equals it goes inside the if statement but radiobutton is not checking. Again in am going wrong anywhere?

Comment: `Model.marlid` has nothing to do with it. Your binding to property `perm_id` (not `marlidid`). Set the value of `perm_id`!

Comment: And stop using `new { checked = true }` - I repeat, its the value of `perm_id` which determines which radio button is selected - thats how model binding works

Comment: My db holds group id 1 and perm_id 3. So when I select group id 1, 3rd permission(which is nothing but 3rd radiobutton) should be checked. So when  if(Model.marlid(3)==permission.perm_id(3)) this executes my radiobutton should be checked.  so I am trying to make checked radiobutton inside this if statement

Comment: I understood perm_id binds value to radiobutton but all I am talking about retrieving data and it is not about saving data

Comment: There is a confusion Anyway thank you

Comment: OMG. Can you not understand what model binding is. Assuming the radio buttons your generating have value attributes `1`, `2`, `3` and `4` (i.e the values of `permission.perm_id`) then in the controller if your set `model.perm_id = 2;` the the 2nd radio button will be selected!

Comment: Yes exactly.  This contains   marlid=db.ts_grp_perm_mapping.Select(p=>p.grp_id==id).Count() corresponding id. Here id which we are supplying based on dropdown change

Comment: I give up. You need to go to the MVC site and learn the basics

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can change the code given below

```
if(ViewBag.marlid != null && Model.Permissions != null)
    {
        foreach(var permission in Model.Permissions)
        {
           if(ViewBag.marlid == permission.perm_id)
           {
              <label>
                @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.perm_id, permission.perm_id,new { @checked = true } )@Model.marlid.ToString()
                <span>@permission.perm_levelname</span>
            </label>
           }
        }
    }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Or your could just delete all this nonsense and use `model.perm_id = db.ts_grp_perm_mapping.Select(p => p.grp_id == id).Count();` in the view so that you bind to the model and MVC is designed to do.

Comment: but these kind of action are to done controller side only.

Comment: I have no idea what your last comment is trying to say. The code I have showed in my last comment is code in the controller. And using it means all the pointless `if(ViewBag.marlid != null && Model.Permissions != null)` and `if(ViewBag.marlid == permission.perm_id)` can be removed.

Comment: ya sure we can do that, but his question is to compare a viewbag value with another value